# What is the difference between Notification and NotificationManger in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

What is the difference between those two?

I want to use the startForeground method and cannot use it with NotificationManager..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Notification is a class that represents either a persistent icon that goes in the status bar and is accessible through the launcher, turning on or flashing LEDs on the device, or alerting the user by flashing the backlight, playing a sound, or vibrating.

The Notification Manager is the class that allows you to add notifications to the system,

`startForeground` is a method of the `Serivce` class. For example inside your Service class you can have something like this.

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_play)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(someText);
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Notification` is a description of what you want to occur to alert the user about something -- what icon goes in the status bar, what ringtone to play, etc.

`NotificationManager` is a system service that can show a `Notification`.

> I want to use the startForeground methode and cannot use it with NotificationManager

Correct. Create a `Notification` using `Notification.Builder` (or `NotificationCompat.Builder`). See [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Foreground) for an example of using `startForeground()`.